# What are differences between javax.tv.xlet.Xlet and javax.microedition.xlet.Xlet?

Tags: java-me, television, cdc, xlet

Wikipedia is saying...

> Accordingly Xlet has later been re-introduced as a part of Personal
>   Basis Profile in *javax.microedition.xlet* package, which is ***slightly
>   different*** from the original design in Java TV specification.

I couldn't find any significant differences between [javax.tv.xlet.Xlet](http://docs.oracle.com/javame/config/cdc/opt-pkgs/api/jsr927/javax/tv/xlet/Xlet.html) and [javax.microedition.xlet.Xlet](http://docs.oracle.com/javame/config/cdc/ref-impl/pbp1.1.2/jsr217/javax/microedition/xlet/Xlet.html)

Is there any aspects that those two interface definitions imply different to each other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question interested me, so I searched a bit.
I don't have a definitive answer, but here's something to think about:

Java TV was originally created to be used for set-top boxes and alike. As you know, the "X" in the name was originally a placeholder. The name was meant to change, but never did. Instead, the "X" became synonym for "Unknown" and should tell us that Xlets could be used a lot of places, not only for Digital TV.

Obviously, the existing implementation of `Xlet` was created for specific platforms in mind, meaning it wouldn't be of any use for other platforms.
In short, whenever `Xlet` was to be used for other platforms, it would need to be re-implemented to fit that platform.
Which class to use depends on your target platform.

From the HD Cookbook, Chapter 16: "`XletContext` and `Xlet` are defined in the Java TV packages `javax.tv.xlet`, and in the PBP packages `javax.microedition.xlet`. Blu-ray xlets must use the Java TV version of the interface, and not the PBP version."
This is somewhat funny, since Blu-ray Xlets reside within the PBP packages. Yet, we must use the Java TV version of the interface to create blu-ray Xlets.

So what is the PBP version of the interface meant for? Good question.
My best guess is: Hardware devices like printers with 7" displays.